# Filtering rows in R when less than half rowcells meet a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, cell

I've got a matrix with 276 column samples and 215000 rows. The values range from zero to some non negative value.

I will use mtcars as simplified example

I need to filter out the rows where less than 50% (could be any percentage) of samples don't reach certain value, for example 1.

Example Matrix:

```
Tmtcars <- t(mtcars[1:5,c(2, 8:11)])
```

I need to select rows where at least 50% of cells are equal or greater than 1.

Only the row “vs = c(0,0,1,1,0)” does not met this condition. As only 2 cells (40%) are 1 or larger.

The row “am = c(1,1,1,0,0)” should be selected as 3 cells (60%) are equal or larger than 1.

If i run the rowMeans function

```
Filtered <- Tmtcars[(rowMeans(Tmtcars) >= 1 ) >=0.5, ]
```

the row "am" is not selected.

The selection criteria has to be whether 50% of cells meet a criteria, nothing to do with average.

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably use something like `DF3[rowMeans(DF3[,1:20] > 2) < 0.5,]`, but it's hard to say without a reproducible example. Can you share the output of `dput(head(DF3))`?

Comment: Probably better to use a matrix or to put it in long-form if you want a data frame. Long form would make sense if you have differing numbers of samples, maybe. Rowwise operations are usually inefficient on data frames.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question for clarity and a reproducible example. I can format my DF to a matrix.

Comment: With your example, the code would be `Tmtcars[rowMeans(Tmtcars >= 1) >= .5,]` (almost what you wrote, but `>= 1` should be operating on `Tmtcars` inside the `rowMeans` parentheses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums()`:

```
set.seed(1)
sample1 <- c(sample(1:10, 5))
sample2 <- c(sample(1:10, 5))
sample3 <- c(sample(1:10, 5))
sample4 <- c(sample(1:10, 5))
sample5 <- c(sample(1:10, 5))

df <- data.frame(sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5)

df2 <- df[rowSums(df > 2) > (ncol(df)/2),]
```

You can obviously play with the values. The first `2` is the value to compare with, the second `2` is looking for the rows where the comparison match is more than 50%.

Comment: I'm still sticking to my answer :) `filtered <- Tmtcars[rowSums(Tmtcars >= 1) > (ncol(Tmtcars)/2),]`

Answer (score 0):

True/False parameters have numeric values in R.

```
TRUE + TRUE ; FALSE + FALSE ; FALSE + TRUE
```

You can use this feature and sum to select a number of rows

```
sum( 5 == c( 3, 5, 5, 2))
```

You can subset rows like this.  When the condition is true more than 5 times, than we subset based on the condition

```
if( sum( mtcars$mpg >20 ) > 5 ) mtcars[  mtcars$mpg >20 , ]
```

You can also create logical vectors, to subset or create a new var

```
# more than five times - mpg greater than 20
    rows <- rep(sum( mtcars$mpg >20 ) > 5, nrow( mtcars))  & mtcars$mpg >20 

# more than 25 times
    rowshigher <- rep(sum( mtcars$mpg >20 ) > 25, nrow( mtcars))  & mtcars$mpg >20 

mtcars[ rows , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can do with

```
DF3[rowMeans(DF3[,1:20]) > 2 )>0.5, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I've adapted some of the answers and I ended up with 3 ways that give me the same results

```
F1 <- Tmtcars[rowSums(Tmtcars >= 1) >= (ncol(Tmtcars)/2), ]

F1b <- Tmtcars[rowMeans(Tmtcars >= 1) >= 0.5, ]

F2 <- Tmtcars[apply(Tmtcars, 1, function(x) mean(x>=1)>=0.5),]
```